# Replacing Fid column using ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-9.3

I want to use the "Feature Vertices to points" and in the outcome the sorting of the points be based on different sorting than the preset Fid. I believe that the solution would be to somehow change the sorting on Fid or create a new column with the correct sorting and make it somehow the new Fid.

Is it possible because I can't find a way?

I am using the ArcMap 9.3.

Comment: ArcMap 9.3 is ***ancient*** and has untolded vulnreabilities. You really shouldn't have it on any machine. Note that it's not possible to sort a shapefile on anything but FID, because FID is the record ID number. Sorting the dBase without the geometries will irreversibly corrupt the feature class.

Answer (score 0):

The [Sort (Data Management) tool](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/data-management-toolbox/sort.htm) can be used to reorder, in ascending or descending order, records in a feature class, shapefile, or table based on one or multiple fields. The reordered result is written to a new dataset.

[Tech Support how-to run the tool](https://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000012218)